# MSDTC (Distributed Transaction Coordinator) Service Stops Unexpectedly

Tags: msdtc

I am working on a Windows Server 2008, the MSDTC (Distributed Transaction Coordinator) Service Stops Unexpectedly and I cannot restart it again.

When I go to the event viewer this is the error message that I have got:
"A critical error occurred in an MS DTC component therefore the process is terminating. The category field identifies the component that encountered the error. Please contact Microsoft Product Support. Error Specifics: hr = 0x80070002, d:\rtm\com\complus\dtc\dtc\msdtc\src\cservice.cpp:473, CmdLine: C:\Windows\System32\msdtc.exe, Pid: 4504"

Does someone know how can I restart that service?

Thanks you very much for your help;
Sergio

Comment: I managed.

After too much reading and getting more confused, finnaly I find the solution.

After restarting the machine , I went to Run command window and I typed in :  msdtc -resetlog.

Then I re-start the service again and it started without a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed.

After too much reading and getting more confused, finally I find the solution.

After restarting the machine, I went to Run command window and I typed in there:

```
MSDTC -resetlog
```

Then I re-start the service again and it started without a problem

GOOD links:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/Q205069

Answer (score 0):

Method 2:

1. Rename the `%SystemRoot%\System32\Dtclog` folder to `Dtclog.old`
2. Create a new `Dtclog` folder in the same location (`%SystemRoot%\System32\Dtclog`)
3. At the command prompt, type the following, and then press `ENTER`: `MSDTC -resetlog`
4. Start the MSDTC service